How would you translate "le rendez-vous du tout Paris" in English?
This is a "famous" French expression and to be honest, I thought Anglophone speakers used it too, I was almost sure I'd heard it before. Some research online and no results. Do you know if there's an equivalent in English ? Or should I just translate by "meeting place of the Parisian elite" or something like that.
Thank you for your help !

Parisian elite or Parisian high society are close enough translations. (Wikipedia suggests "jet set", but it doesn't quite evoke the same mental image to me). Or you could leave it untranslated, in the vein of je ne sais quoi or au contraire, but it's a bit of an obscure term and I wouldn't expect an average English speaker to understand it.

I can second @MaciejStachowski's claim that most English speakers wouldn't understand - I've never heard of it and don't quite understand what it means. Could you provide more explanation or examples of context it would be used in?

I agree that most English speakers wouldn't understand, mainly because most English speakers don't speak French (I have seen 15% as an estimate of UK speakers). Not since poor dear Edward VII passed away have British upper class people routinely known French. Some people will know carte blanche, or raison d’être, but not many!

I know the literal meaning of the phrase, but I'm not aware of it as a set expression. @MaciejStachowski's link is actually to Tout-Paris with a hyphen, which isn't in my Petit Larousse!

Le tout-Londres ne parle bientôt plus que de vampires. — (François Rivière, Dracula, cent ans et toutes ses dents, dans Libération, 31 décembre 1987) ... Moi, je suis d'accord ! Toutes ses dents - j'aime ça !

@KateBunting - in decent/formal written French, set phrases may be hyphenated, thus c'est-à-dire, vis-à-vis, etc. Consider sage-femme (midwife) vs sage femme (wise woman), and le tout-Paris (Parisian high society; masculine le because generic groups, herds, crowds, etc, are deemed to be masculine) vs tout la Paris (everyone in Paris; feminine la because Paris happens to have feminine gender). Note le Tout-Paris (capital T & P) is a restaurant.
